# Add in inclusion

Tags: django

**Django 1.11.4**

Below is DTL.

Could you have a look at the traceback below.
The problem has something to do with "|add:container_classes".
If I remove it, the template doesn't blow up.

Well, I experimented:

1. Printed the variable. It really prints.
2. Changed the variable to a string.

Well, experiment works: template is rendered. And the variable is printed.
And the container gets the class "abracadabra".

ADDED later:

And the experiment_2 works fine. I mean everything is ok: no errors,
class is added to html as was expected.

Could you give me a kick here?

**template**

```
        {% include 'general/inclusions/container/container_block_begin.html' with id_suffix=id classes="margin-top-10 margin-left-10 "|add:container_classes %}

             ...something

        {% include 'general/inclusions/container/container_block_end.html' with id_suffix=id%}
```

**traceback**

```
VariableDoesNotExist at /frames/2/
Failed lookup for key [container_classes] in "[{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {}, {}, {'object': <Frame: 2>, 'frame': <Frame: 2>, 'view': <frames.views.FrameDetailView object at 0x7fef6647fcf8>}]"
```

**experiment**

```
{{ container_classes }}
{% include 'general/inclusions/container/container_block_begin.html' with id_suffix=id classes="margin-top-10 margin-left-10 "|add:"abracadabra" %}

                     ...something        

{% include 'general/inclusions/container/container_block_end.html' with id_suffix=id%}
```

**experiment_2**

```
        {% with container_classes=container_classes %}
        {% include 'general/inclusions/container/container_block_begin.html' with id_suffix=id classes="margin-top-10 margin-left-10 "|add:container_classes %}

                     ...something            

        {% include 'general/inclusions/container/container_block_end.html' with id_suffix=id%}
        {% endwith %}
```

Comment: please, show your view code

Comment: Pardon, I can't catch your idea. What problem can be localized in view?

Comment: does you provide valid context data?

Comment: Well, in the experiment section above I printed  {{ container_classes }}. It shows.

Comment: Failed lookup for key [wrong_key]

Bear brown is right your context data is not valid. Show us your context data if you still need help.

Comment: Well, to the best of my ability I can't see that context data is invalid. I understand that I have made some error here. But I can't localize it. Look: the variable is inside the context. I have shown it on the page in experiment. Could you have a look at the experiment_2. I have just added it to the main post. It works. So, the variable is there.